# The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.1.7:compile could not be retrieved

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

idea2018.3

Scala 2.12 (idea plugin)

play2.6

sbt using the bundled in idea

build.properties `sbt.version=1.1.6` even I change the version to 2 still have this error

[image]

in index server/target/scala-2.12/resolution-cache/org.scala-sbt.temp produce a directory 1.1.7

This project is getting from subversion. It can be compiled successfully in my Mac, when import this project to my development machine(Windows 10) in company. when i run, get the following errors:

```
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt,scaffold.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from D:\server\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to targetingvis_server (in build file:/D:/server/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Server started, use Alt+D to stop
[info] Compiling 12 Scala sources and 1 Java source to D:\server\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
[info] Attempting to fetch org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.1.7.
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#compiler-bridge_2.12;1.1.7: public: unable to get resource for org/scala-sbt#compiler-bridge_2.12;1.1.7: res=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compiler-bridge_2.12/1.1.7/compiler-bridge_2.12-1.1.7.pom: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to repo1.maven.org/151.101.196.209:443
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] ## Exception when compiling 13 sources to D:\server\target\scala-2.12\classes
[error] The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.1.7:compile could not be retrieved.
[error] 
[error]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error]         org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.1.7
[error]           +- org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-98ec89c315ed408f615fff2c4774286d17323b01:1.1.7
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:274)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$3$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:264)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:376)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:383)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$2(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:264)
[error] scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error] sbt.internal.util.BufferedLogger.bufferQuietly(BufferedLogger.scala:106)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:264)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1$adapted(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:261)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:376)
[error] sbt.io.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:383)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.compileAndInstall(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:261)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentCompiler.$anonfun$compiledBridgeJar$1(ZincComponentCompiler.scala:227)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IfMissing$Define.run(IfMissing.scala:19)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.createAndCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:46)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$3(ZincComponentManager.scala:57)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:38)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$2(ZincComponentManager.scala:57)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$lockSecondaryCache$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:84)
[error] scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockSecondaryCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:82)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.fromSecondary$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:55)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$6(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.getOrElse$1(ZincComponentManager.scala:38)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.$anonfun$files$5(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error] xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error] xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lock(ZincComponentManager.scala:87)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ZincComponentManager.scala:78)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.ZincComponentManager.files(ZincComponentManager.scala:61)
[error] application - 

! @7ac7f7pgj - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[InvalidComponent: The compiler bridge sources org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.1.7:compile could not be retrieved.

Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
    org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.1.7
      +- org.scala-sbt.temp:temp-module-98ec89c315ed408f615fff2c4774286d17323b01:1.1.7]
at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1(PlayReload.scala:35)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:28)
at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:24)
at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$compile$3(PlayReload.scala:51)
at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:51)
at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$4(PlayRun.scala:76)
at play.runsupport.Reloader.$anonfun$reload$1(Reloader.scala:412)
at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$5.run(Reloader.scala:50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. This occurs when the SBT cannot access the internet and cannot download the compiler bridge library, e.g. due to proxy.
The compiler bridge is located in the `.sbt` folder (on Windows it is `C:\Users\<user>\.sbt`, on Linux: `~/.sbt`).

As of SBT 1.6.2, the bridge libraries are in `.sbt/1.0/zinc/org.scala-sbt/`:

E.g. `org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.11-1.5.7-bin_2.11.12__52.0-1.5.7_20210712T054328.jar`

One way to fix it is to check if SBT can access the internet. If it is behind a proxy, configure the proxy settings.
The other way to fix it is to copy the `.sbt` folder from a working environment. This can work also for the offline use.